# Why does this header-within-a-blockquote render as expected in the preview but not the final post?

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering, blockquote

I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63183035/150605) that contains a header within a blockquote as follows...

```
> Example 9: Use the -Force parameter to overwrite existing files
> ===============================================================
> 
> ...
```

In the post/edit preview it renders as expected...

[image: Editing from Revision 1 of Stack Overflow answer 63183035: a heading within a blockquote renders as expected]

...but in the displayed post it's just plain text followed by equals signs...

[image: Viewing Revision 1 of Stack Overflow answer 63183035: a heading within a blockquote renders as plain text]

I first tried it without the third, empty blockquote line between the equals signs and the following text...

```
> Example 9: Use the -Force parameter to overwrite existing files
> ===============================================================
> ...
```

...as well as using a fixed number of equals signs...

```
> Example 9: Use the -Force parameter to overwrite existing files
> ===
> ...
```

...but everything rendered the same.  I am using Mozilla Firefox 79.0 on Windows with uBlock Origin in [Medium mode](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Blocking-mode:-medium-mode) and the necessary whitelist rules for Stack Overflow to work properly.

Comment: The CommonMark reference renderer renders it properly, so this is a bug in the Stack Exchange implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After saving [an unrelated edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63183035/2) the header now renders properly.